# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined appears when i run it

Tags: reactjs

Every time I use map function with axios I get this following error.

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**

React Code for API call:

```
import React ,{Component} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
 class Api extends Component{
     state={
         content :[]
     }
componentDidMount =()=>{
    axios.get('js/data.json').then(res=>{this.setState({content : res.data.content})
                                        console.log(this.state.content)})
}

    render(){
        const items=this.state.content ;
        const thecontain= items.map((item)=>{
            return(
            <div>
            <p>{item.name}</p>  
            </div>
            )
        })
                              
            return(
           
     <div>{thecontain}</div>
   )}
}
export default Api
```

Comment: could you please provide API response result in the description?

Comment: Does "items" an array? if not then this "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" will occur.

Comment: @AbuSufian Actually it will only throw that error if `items` is undefined. If it is defined but a different datatype, it will say something like `map` is not a function or does not exist. Most likely `res.data.content` is undefined in the axios response, so the state value is being set from an empty array to `undefined` then throwing the error.

Comment: "items" is an empty array which i put the data in my json file in and i defined it

Comment: @BrianThompson so how should i do the setstate function?

Comment: @HossamThapet have you console logged `res.data.content` before you try to set it to state?

Comment: Please console log `res` inside the axios callback and add the output to the question.

Comment: when i did console.log(res) data appeard in the console
but when i did setState(content:res.data) after console.log the error back again

Comment: I'm asking you to show us the data that appeared in the console, because my suggestion is that it's not in the format that your code is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

```
    render(){
    const items=this.state.content;
    let thecontain = null; 
    if(typeof this.state.content === 'object'){
      if(this.state.content.constructor.name == "Array"){
         thecontain= items.map((item)=>{
        return (
           <div>
            <p>{item.name}</p>  
           </div>
        )
      })
     }
    }
        return(
       
        <div>{thecontain}</div>
     )
  }
```

Comment: please check `items` array value. may be it is [] i.e no item there.

Comment: items is my json flie it has the data

Comment: @HossamThapet i have updated my answer. the issue was checking type array . fixed it using `if(this.state.content.constructor.name == "Array")`

Comment: [Array.isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) - no need to go into the contructor..

Answer (score 0):

In general one of the reasons for `TypeError` to be thrown is when you are trying to perform a method which is incompatible with the type of `this.state.content` from the error in your question, if it is thrown from here then it means you are trying to access map from undefined type which in general doesn't exist. `map` is a prototype method which is present in arrays so check if the `this.state.content` is array or not, if array use it, if not default it to array such that you won't get a type error if the `TypeError` from question is from here. It would be clear if Stack trace would have been included in the question.

```
const items=Array.isArray(this.state.content)? this.state.content:[];
const thecontain= items.map((item)=>{
    return(
    <div>
    <p>{item.name}</p>  
    </div>
    )
})

    return(
        <div>{thecontain}</div>
    )       
}
```

Comment: actually no errors appears put the data is not  appear too

Comment: what does "put the data is not appear too" mean

Comment: I m wondering why you are using axios to fetch a file in your local dir

Comment: This doesn't solve this problem, it just makes the problem harder to find. They have initialized `this.state.content` to an empty array, so checking that its an array will not fix the problem. The problem has to do with `this.state.contents` **becoming** undefined later in the cycle.

Comment: "The error indicates that you are trying to access a property/method which doesn't exists" this just isn't true. It indicates that `items` (thereby `this.state.content`) is `undefined`.

Comment: Calm down Type Error has many reasons to be thrown I just gave a general statement you can read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError and also Question is not clear may be you can edit the question if you understand what exactly the question supposed to be

Comment: Yes "TypeError" has many reasons, but "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" does not. Its only thrown when it attempts to do the operation `undefined.map`, which tells us that `items` (and `this.state.content`) is undefined. Based on this line from the question `state={ content :[] }` we know that `items` is defined as an array when the component mounts. So the only possible cause for the error is that it is set to `undefined` sometime after that point. The most probable point being this line `this.setState({content : res.data.content})`.

Comment: I don't want to argue with you but I don't get what exactly you are trying to say may be an answer from you would help that. I mean I know when that error occurs may be you can explain that to the one who asked question.
Actual problem in question being it is not clear from where the TypeError is being throw. My answer gives description of what TypeError is and helps to fix issue if error is thrown from the place I thought. I dont know how you can be sure that TypeError is being throw from this.state.content without the stack trace what if the error is thrown from axios package.